# PHP: Adding options to Session array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, session-variables, addition

During an order procedure, I have a step in which multiple options can be chosen to add to an order. I am storing this in the session, so that it appears in my cart and order summary.

My question now is, I got code working to add just one option. However, it is required that multiple options can be added.

The current situation is that every step in the ordering proces has a view.html.php and a default.php (controller and view).

For this specific step in the process (adding options), I ended up with the following code:

In view.html.php:

```
if(JRequest::getVar('reset')) {
                unset ($_SESSION['selectedoptions'][$plan->id]);    
                $mainframe->redirect(html_entity_decode(JRoute::_( '$url')));
            }
            elseif(JRequest::getVar('add')){
                $_SESSION['selectedoptions'][] = $plan->id;
                $mainframe->redirect(html_entity_decode(JRoute::_( '$url')));
            }
```

And in default.php:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['selectedoptions'][$plan->id])): ?>
            <input class="btn-address btn-address-text" type="submit" name="reset" value="Verwijderen" />
        <?php else: ?>
            <input class="btn-address btn-address-text" type="submit" name="add" value="Toevoegen" />
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I would like the functionality to add an option to an array such that later, I can read the array values to display the items chosen. What am I doing wrong ?

Hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if value exists the wrong way.

You do:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['selectedoptions'][$plan->id])): ?>
```

You should do

```
<?php if(in_array($plan->id, $_SESSION['selectedoptions'])): ?>
```

**EDIT**

But possible looking also for for `unset`, you set this value the wrong way.

Instead of:

```
$_SESSION['selectedoptions'][] = $plan->id;
```

you should do:

```
$_SESSION['selectedoptions'][$plan->id] = 1;
```

And then your code in `default.php` should work

**EDIT2**

Into your default.php file you should add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="plan_id" value="<?php echo $plan->id; ?>" />
```

at the beginning of the code you showed.

And in viev.html.php you should change your code into:

```
if(JRequest::getVar('reset')) {
                unset ($_SESSION['selectedoptions'][JRequest::getVar('plan_id')]);    
                $mainframe->redirect(html_entity_decode(JRoute::_( '$url')));
            }
            elseif(JRequest::getVar('add')){
                $_SESSION['selectedoptions'][JRequest::getVar('plan_id')] =  1;
                $mainframe->redirect(html_entity_decode(JRoute::_( '$url')));
            }
```

Comment: Have you added `session_start() ;` at the same beginning of your PHP file?

Comment: So probably problem is somewhere else. Maybe you don't have anything in `$_SESSION`, maybe you don't go into your statements. It's hard to say without var_dump and more information from you

Comment: I am currently printing the array $_SESSION['selectedoptions'] for debugging, so I can see what is in it. But it only prints array. So I assume adding items to the array is not working.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['selectedoptions']) prints this: array(1) { [1]=> int(1) }.

Comment: So you have one element in this array with index 1. So in `default.php` when you check <?php `if(isset($_SESSION['selectedoptions'][$plan->id])): ?>` and have set `$plan->id` value to 1 you should have displayed reset button

Comment: That is the problem, $plan->id is not equal to one. Currently I have two cases, 8 and 3.

Comment: So it's obvious it won't work. As you add to your session 1 and then check if 8 or 3 is set in array it won't be set because you haven't add it earlier

Comment: I think the problem is that in view.html.php the value $plan->id is not available, or different. Is there any way I can pass on it's value from default.php ? With something like <input class="btn-address btn-address-text" type="submit" name="add[$plan->id]" value="Toevoegen" />  ?

Comment: Great, now I can see it is added to the array. Thanks a lot! How do I now need to change my if statement so that the right button is displayed ? It currently is: <?php if(in_array($plan->id, $_SESSION['selectedoptions'])): ?>

Comment: I cannot help you more with this question. Mark this question as complete and create new one with clear problem and code. Now I even don't know what are you asking again